# Why files in `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/` are not taken into acount?

Tags: neovim, filetype, filetype-ruby

My neovim doesn't load file type plugins when loading a ruby/eruby file. Here is the corresponding configuration files:

```
for f in ~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/* ; do echo "# $f" ; cat $f; done
# /home/psychoslave/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/erb.vim
" Turn off vi compatibility
set nocompatible

set smartindent
set noautoindent
set filetype=ruby
filetype indent off
filetype plugin indent on
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
"set ai "Auto indent
"set si "Smart indent
"set wrap "Wrap line
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set filetype=eruby
# /home/psychoslave/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/eruby.vim
" Turn off vi compatibility
set nocompatible

set smartindent
set noautoindent
set filetype=ruby
filetype indent off
filetype plugin indent on
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
"set ai "Auto indent
"set si "Smart indent
"set wrap "Wrap line
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set filetype=eruby
# /home/psychoslave/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim
" Turn off vi compatibility
set nocompatible

set smartindent
set noautoindent
set filetype=ruby
filetype indent off
filetype plugin indent on
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
"set ai "Auto indent
"set si "Smart indent
"set wrap "Wrap line
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

But when I open a ruby file, it doesn't have tab set to 2 spaces and so on.

I did added `filetype plugin indent on` in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

Once running, trying to launch `:so ~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/eruby.vim` will lead to the following error, repeated multiple times:

```
line    6:                                                                                                                             
E218: autocommand nesting too deep                                                                                                     
Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "*":                                                                        
E218: autocommand nesting too deep
```

How can I resolve this problem? Is there a way to list what configuration files a neovim red and in which order?

Comment: also the configuration is set as `runtimepath=~/.config/nvim,~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start/vim-vue,/etc/xdg/nvim,~/.local/share/nvim/site,~/.local/share/flatpak/ex
ports/share/nvim/site,/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/nvim/site,/usr/local/share/nvim/site,/usr/share/nvim/site,/usr/share/nvim/runtime,
/usr/share/nvim/site/after,/usr/local/share/nvim/site/after,/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/nvim/site/after,~/.local/share/flatpak/expor
ts/share/nvim/site/after,~/.local/share/nvim/site/after,/etc/xdg/nvim/after,~/.config/nvim/after`

Comment: do not set the filetype in your ftplugin. Only put there the settings you want to be applied for your filetype. So for ruby put all required indenting settings into the `ftplugin/ruby.vim` file

Comment: Thank you @ChristianBrabandt I followed both your recommandations but still not have the expected result.

Comment: Try `:checkhealth` with Nvim 0.2.2 or later. It looks for problems with $VIMRUNTIME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure your basic configuration has filetype enabled to begin with:
`filetype plugin on`

If it is, but sill not working as intended, you can set filetypes explicitly:

Something like this should be in your `~/.vimrc` or `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` depending on whichever editor you are actually using:

```
augroup MyRubyCode
" Files with extension .rb are processed as Ruby code
    automcd!
    autocmd BufReadPre,FileReadPre *.rb set ft=ruby
augroup END
```

This will pick up whatever ruby file attributes set in your **proper** vim path ftplugin:
e.g, `/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin`
(this is the actual path for both vim and neovim in a Fedora 27 distribution).

I believe you just want the MyRubyCode above so (probably) remove the custom files from your personal ftplugin folder.

e.g, `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin`

e.g, `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin`

The files you are putting there are doing silly things that don't help your cause. i.e., setting the file as a ruby file after it had been recognized as a ruby file. (**filetype recognition happens before** ftplugin so it doesn't make sense).  That's why you should use your vim config file instead of fiddling with paths you don't fully understand yet.

**Notice:** if you don't want to fiddle with file extensions, just open the file and type `:set ft=ruby` in Vim's command line. If you want to make the change permanent, just use some Vim magic *(modeline)* at the very end of the file.

`# vim: set ft=ruby`

Enjoy.

Comment: Great, now it seems it works again. Actually I made the following: remove `set filetype=ruby ` from `after/ftplugin/ruby.vim`, removed `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin`, add `filetype plugin on` at the end of `~/.config/vim/vimrc` which is loaded when nvim is runned as `so ~/.config/vim/vimrc` is included in ` ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

Comment: Actually, when editing erb files I no longer have corect syntax highlight with this solution. Do you have an idea why @Mario? I did try with an explicit `set ft=eruby`.

Comment: Have you tried this? `vim -c 'set ft=eruby' document`.  Remember: if document is document.*rb* it will probably default to ruby. Try to use another extension (if your system is overriding your defaults).

Comment: I tried that (with nvim), but still have `ruby` set as file type in the end. Actually it seems that when `eruby` is assigned, `ft` is actually set to `ruby` on my system.

Comment: 1. check whether reopening the file does the trick. 2. try also with :set syntax=eruby 3. If you removed the custom files in your local ftp I'm out of ideas.  In case of panic `nvim -u NORC` to check out whether the problem is your init.vim config file.  Good luck!.

Comment: `:set syntax=eruby` seems to works, thank you.

Comment: I added it to `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/eruby.vim` and now everything is already working as I would expect, thank you. :)